# Ordered lists in Doxygen comments from C# .NET comments

Tags: c#, doxygen, xml-comments, doxywizard

I've got some C# documentation comments that looks like this:

```
/// <para>
/// Pre-Conditions:
/// </para>
/// <para>
///     1. The sky must be clear.
/// </para>
/// <para>
///     2. It must be night time.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// Post-Conditions:
/// </para>
/// <para>
///     1. A picture of the sky will be saved.
/// </para>
/// <para>
///     2. Some second thing will be true that I can't think of.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// Invariants:
/// </para>
/// <para>
///     1. Existing pictures will not be changed.
/// </para>
void TakePictureOfStars();
```

I made everything its own paragraph so it shows up correctly when I use the mouse-over tool tips in Visual Studio.

I used Doxygen to generate the comments, but I keep getting the following HTML:

```
<ol type="1">
    <li>The sky must be clear.</li>
</ol>
<ol type="1">
    <li>It must be night time.</li>
</ol>
```

That looks like this:

```
1. The sky must be clear.

1. It must be night time.
```

So, here's the question: how can I get each numbered item to show up on its own line in the Visual Studio tool tip AND get an ordered list in my code output?

Comment: This is probably related to Markdown support. Try setting MARKDOWN_SUPPORT to NO in the config file.

Comment: Thank you very much, @doxygen!  Would you like to convert your comment to an answer so I can give you credit?  Do you also happen to know if there's a way to preserve the leading spaces?  Sometimes I have a, b, and c under 2, for example, and a, b, and c are indented in my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `MARKDOWN_SUPPORT` to `NO` will avoid that 1. 2. 3. markers are treated as ordered lists.

To preserve spaces you could use `<pre>` and `</pre>`:

```
/// <para><pre>
/// Pre-Conditions:
/// </pre></para>
/// <para><pre>
///     1. The sky must be clear.
/// </pre></para>
/// <para><pre>
///     2. It must be night time.
///        a. half moon
///        b. full moon
/// </pre></para>
```